# Is there a way to combine ease-in and linear in the CSS3 -animation-timing-function?

Tags: css-transitions

I am asking because I am working on making a vinyl record ease into motion, and then it needs to rotate at constant speed. I can make it rotate at contant easily, and ease-in-out easily by adding these classes:

```
#label_vinyl.rotate {
    -webkit-animation-name:             rotate; 
    -webkit-animation-duration:         12s; 
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
}

#label_vinyl.ease {
    -webkit-animation-name:             rotate; 
    -webkit-animation-duration:         12s; 
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
}
```

my problem is making the switch from one class to the other. When I try and replace the class ease class with the rotate class. Or if i have both classes added first (making the ease-in override since it is last), and then removing the ease class, it still has the 'easing animation', even when the ease class is no longer attached to my div/img.

It is as if the ease-in sticks forever even when i change classes. My question is: is there a way to combine the two or chain them? something on the lines of:

```
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1, infinity;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in, linear;
```

the former does not work btw.

EDIT: if there isnt, there really should be! :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you just use jQuery to control the classes?

```
$('#label_vinyl').toggleClass('ease','rotate');
```

or were you wanting to do this all CSS?

Comment: thx for your answer kcdwayne, but I've tried solutions like with javascript.

Comment: You can use jQuery/Javascript. but its not the script giving me issues, because I can add/remove the classes without a problem, but for some reason, even though I have removed the 'ease' class, it still eases in for every rotation